# Telegram webapp:Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid

Tags: java, reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot

I am try to send post request from my web app to Telegram method answerWebAppQuery. but dont't recived any response.

my react request code(don't recived response)

```
   sendPost() {
        const query_id = window.Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe.query_id;
        const data = { "web_app_query_id": query_id, "result": { "title": "send successful!", "type": "article", "id": "223", "input_message_content": { "message_text": "test" } } };
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert("sendPost!");
        axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<mytoken>/answerWebAppQuery', {
            // Add parameters here
            data
        })
            .then((response) => {
                alert("response");
                console.log(response.data);
                alert(response.data);
                // Handle data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert(error);
            })
        alert("finsh");
    }
```

and then,i am try to copy the query_id from webapp to send post use java code ,the server response "Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid".

I think of my post is correct,it's not that old.
.how can i solve this error? thanks

my java post code:

```
String url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<mytoken>";
        String json= "{\"web_app_query_id\":\"AAGHzz5tAAAAAIfPPm0MZw_9\n\",\"result\":{\"title\":\"send test for successful!\",\"type\":\"article\",\"id\":\"2231234223\",\"input_message_content\":{\"message_text\":\"test\"}}}";
        post(url,json);
        System.out.println(post(url,json));
```

Comment: try to change my react post method , i have recived response still 400. but the error message is Bad Request: result isn't specified

Comment: I have solved this problem!!!